# How to write a method of interface in a class?

Tags: java, methods, interface

I have to code a method of interface in a class where method will search the list of pets for every pet boarding at the given time and print the pet’s information for every match, using the toString() method.

the interface is

```
public interface Boardable {
void setBoardStart(int month, int day, int year);
void setBoardEnd(int month, int day, int year);
boolean boarding(int month, int day, int year); }
```

a class with boarding getter and setter is

```
public class Cat extends Pet implements Boardable { 
private int sMonth, eMonth;
private int sDay, eDay;
private int sYear, eYear;
@Override
public void setBoardStart(int month, int day, int year)
{
    sMonth = month;
    sDay = day;
    sYear = year;
}

@Override
public void setBoardEnd(int month, int day, int year)
{
    eMonth = month;
    eDay = day;
    eYear = year;
}

@Override
public boolean boarding(int month, int day, int year)
{
    if(month >= sMonth && month <= eMonth && day >=sDay && day <= eDay && year >= sYear && year <= eYear)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}}
```

my problem is i cannot understand how to code the following

```
import java.util.*;

public class AnimalHospital
{
public static ArrayList<Pet> list = new ArrayList<Pet>();

public AnimalHospital()
{
}

public void addPet(Pet p)
{
    list.add(p);
}
public void printPetsBoarding(int month, int day, int year)
{
    //what to write here?
}
}
```

Comment: You seem to be asking for us to write the code for you. You should try writing a solution yourself and if it's not working, ask a specific question about that failure.

Answer (score 0):

The method inside an interface should be written inside that calls that implements the interface. Which you have done in you `Cat` class.

To call those methods you just call them how do it normally, by `object.method()`

**For example :**

```
Cat c = new Cat();
c.setBoardStart(1,2,3);
```